Deserializing JSON when node key is dynamic Id
I'm integrating with an API that returns nested json where the inner node is a dynamic, variable id number.  Here's the API's response.
{ "appointmentids": { "123456": "10:00" } }

The "123456" is a key that changes with every record/response.  So the next time we might get a whole different id number.
I've been told that JSON.deserializeUntyped can be used for this.  But it only gets the parent node, not the child.  Here's an example:
String jsonInput = '{ "appointmentids": { "123456": "10:00" } }';
Map<String, Object> m = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(jsonInput);
system.debug(m.get('appointmentids'));
//DEBUG|{281077=10:00}

Is there something else I can do to reliably grab the "123456" external id for later use in my code?  I'd hate to fall back to string manipulation...
